# Where is the code in HOI4 that defines how an AI decides on events (e.g. "Split Czechoslovakia")?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I cannot find the code, that defines how an AI decides on an event that is triggered by another countries focus. In particular I cannot find how Germany decides whether or not to "Split Czechoslovakia", after Romania finished this focus?

In the file "Hearts of Iron IV/common/national_focus/romania.txt" I found the following code:

```
focus = {
    id = ROM_split_czechoslovakia

    [... some other code ...]

    completion_reward = {
        GER = { country_event = DOD_romania.110 }
    }
}
```

But I could not find where "DOD_romania.110" is defined. Can anybody help me out?

I ran several different games and Germany always denied the Split - even if I Increased Relations to 100. This is really annoying because shortly afterwards Germany will Demand Sudentenland and in non-historic might have to attack Czechoslovakia - and now I am asked to honor my Guarantee of Czechoslovakia to fight Germany and Italy in 1938 with Czechoslovakia as my only ally and being the only major on my side (good luck). So I would really like to know how the AI decides this.

Answer (score 1):

The event in question is in "Hearts of Iron IV\events\DOD_Romania.txt". That event has 2 options. 90% to agree to split, 10% to disagree. Also, there's 0 chance for split if Germany and Czechs are in a faction together.

Are you sure it's the Germany who denies the split and not the Czechs? If Germany denies, you're given the option to get claims or back off, if Czechs refuse after Germany agrees, Germany, Hungary and you all get a war goal

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I am sure that Germany disagrees to the split. And yes, I am getting the claims. But it takes time to justify a wargoal, even with claims. And in this time Germany often annexed Czech or even worse, attacked them and thereby forcing me to either honor my guarantee and fight the Germans or lose 20 % stability.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that you're so unlucky to trigger the same outcome several times. How many attempts like this have you got?